# Como utilizar, instalar, free template for BootStrap 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-3

Estou com uma tremenda duvida sobre esse tipo de theme, estou começando a mecher com ASP.NET MVC, então me deparei com o tal do BootStrap, então comecei a pesquisar sobre free themes e temos varias opções disponíveis.

Um dos sites que achei foi: [BootsWatch](https://bootswatch.com/)

Onde basta subistituir os arquivos Bootstrap.cs e Bootstrap.min.cs, que automaticamente o thema é alterado.

Também achei site como: [peckyboy](https://speckyboy.com/free-bootstrap-admin-themes/), onde achamos o tema: `Gentelella Bootstrap Admin Template`, que nos direciona para o [GitHub](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella) do projeto.

Ai que vem minha duvida, como posso utilizar esse projeto?

Ao ler o README do projeto:

```
Installation via Package Manger

Our goal is to make it installable on different Package Manager! Do you want to use it on your favorite Package Manager and you know how? Pull request all the way!

As of now, this is some installation available:

Bower

bower install gentelella --save

or
npm

npm install gentelella --save
```

Porém, como utilizo? alguém trabalha com algo parecido?

Arquivos do projeto `Gentelella` como utiliza-los?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bootstrap é um framework para deixar o seu site resposivo, que se adapta aos tablets e smatphones. Para utilizar você precisa ter os arquivos mencionados: Bootstrap.cs e Bootstrap.min.cs e dentro de cada tag HTML usar a class que prefirir.  [Mais informações](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: @EmanuelF desculpe, acho que você não entendeu a pergunta. Quando você cria um projeto Asp.Net MVC 5, o bootstrap é padrão, porém na internet achamos templates prontos, para você ir modificando, porém não é simplismente trocar os arquivos bootstrap.cs e bootstrap.min.cs gostaria de saber qual o procedimento para usar esses outros modelos

Comment: OK, Acho que agora entendi. Imagino que ja tenha feito o download de algum tamplate free. Vem uma pasta com todos os arquivos necessários, arquivo HTML, pasta de imagem, js, css e outros. Basta instanciar esses arquivos para dentro do teu projeto no VS e alterar o arquivo HTML.

Comment: @EmanuelF fiz uma revisão na pergunta, aonde acho os arquivos html?

Comment: [Free Tampletes](https://shapebootstrap.net/free-templates) nesse site tem vários tamplates free, precisar criar uma conta pra fazer os dowloads. Assim que fazer o download você vai encontrar os arquivos que te falei.

Comment: Thomas, você conseguiu resolver essa questão?

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta não é lá muito relacionada com `github`, pois sua dúvida é sobre como implementar o tema que foi baixado de lá, e não sobre como usar o `gihub` efetivamente.

O `gentelella` não tem segredo: é só um tema CSS responsivo para painéis de controle. Depois de baixar, todos os documentos para uso estão dentro de `/node_modules/gentelella/production`.

Eu usei `npm install gentelella --save` dentro de `/usr/share/css`. depois de instalar você pode fazer suas adaptações linkando tudo pra cá.

Primeiro, eu criei um `alias` no `Apache` pra poder ver a documentação:

```
    Alias /gentelella "/usr/share/css/node_modules/gentelella"
    <Directory "/usr/share/css/node_modules/gentelella">
            Options FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Use `http://localhost/gentelella/documentation` pra ver a documentação; 
Use `http://localhost/gentelella/production` pra ver funcionando.

**Alternativamente**: salve os arquivos diretamente na raiz do servidor web.

Se você reparar os arquivos dentro de `/node_modules/gentelella/production` (veja `index.html`) vai ver que eles estão linkados para as bibliotecas locais:

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- iCheck -->
<link href="../vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
<link href="../vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- jVectorMap -->
<link href="css/maps/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Custom Theme Style -->
<link href="../build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Dê ao seu `webserver` acesso a essas bibliotecas e use a lógica pra fazer funcionar com o seu projeto/framework.